# How SSL works with the website with Spring rest API or any other rest API

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, spring-rest

I have created a simple spring rest service. 
I created a SSL certificate using keytool of java. 
I have added following spring rest controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SecuredServerController {

    @RequestMapping("/secured")
    public String secured(){
        System.out.println("Inside secured()");
        return "Hello user !!! : " + new Date();
    }
}
```

I have added following properties in the 'application.properties'.

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsigned_localhost_sslserver
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl-server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Following is the snapshot of my application.

[image]

Now, once I run my api, I get the following 'warning' on browser:

[image]

I have to proceed to unsafe browsing to see the API result.

Now, my question is whenever we visit websites like Facebook or gmail or any 'https' sites we do not get this warning, why?
Why only my api shows this warning.

Comment: Certificates of facebook.com or gmail.com are signed by trusted Certifying Authority. 
since you are using a self signed certificate which is signed by yourself, your browser cannot trust the CA hence you are getting the error.

Comment: Can I make some settings at my browser, so that atleast I can not see this error.

Comment: just click on "Advanced" and click on "Proceed to localhost:8443/secured (unsafe)" link. 
You can use this for testing and development. But DO NOT ever do this in production.

Comment: When I make my REST api as https with valid certificate on prod environment then is it possible that I access my REST urls by Angular 4 UI or jQuery UI or any other java-script based UI ???
Will it throw any error of certificate required or something ?